# How to recover killed entities with a backup

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was playing around with the kill command (did `@e` instead of `@p`) and accidentally killed everything. I have a backup of my world from a week ago. I was wondering if I can somehow move the entities from the backup to my world? I only want the entities, not blocks, because I just made an awesome build and don't want to lose it.

P.S. I'm not on a server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible however would require editing region data in your minecraft world. It is possible using something like [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) to copy and paste the compound tag containing all the data about the entities from each chunk into the same chuck in the new world. This would require you to manually copy and paste each chunk's entity compound tag into each chunk of your new world but if you are willing to do that then here is how you would go about it.

---

First you would need to download a tool for editing the NBT data in your world. Personally I use NBTExplorer which you can download [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac)

Once you have downloaded an editor open up your minecraft saves folder inside the editor. Then you will need to navigate to the chunk you wish to copy. For instance here I found the chunk at 0,0 and have opened that.[image]

Then you will need to navigate to the compound tag which contains the entity information and copy it as shown.
[image]

Then navigate to the same chunk on the new world and paste it as shown.[image]

Finally the new chunk should look like this if all worked. The process will need to be repeated for all chunks that need copying. You will also need to click the save button once finished.
[image]

Comment: Boy will this take a long time.

Comment: @aytimothy Yeah, I don't know of any faster methods however if someone were to do it then it may be better just copy the chunks with the most important entities and leave the rest.

Comment: Yay! It works. Thanks for your answer. It's Really appreciated!

Comment: @Eddy2000 Great! Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

McEdit should be able to do this. I've only used it a little bit. It does have a way to copy and past stuff, so it probably has a way to only copy entities.